# Data binding in gridview column using eval

Tags: c#, asp.net

I hava grid containing a column for displaying countrynames. I need to display value in that column as contrycode-first 10 letters of country name (in-India) .I tried it using Eval functions with in the item template:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="CountryNameLabe" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CorporateAddressCountry").SubString(0,6) %>' ></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

But it shows error.
Can i use custom functions in eval?
please help

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: It was in there, it just wasn't showing because it had html markers in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator `?`:

```
<asp:Label ID="CountryNameLabel" runat="server" 
    Text='<%# Eval("CorporateAddressCountry").ToString().Length <= 10 ? Eval("CorporateAddressCountry") : Eval("CorporateAddressCountry").ToString().Substring(0,10) %>' >
</asp:Label>
```

Another, in my opinion more readable, way is to use GridView's [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event:

```
protected void Gridview1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var row = (DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem;
        var CountryNameLabel = (Label) e.Row.FindControl("CountryNameLabel");
        String CorporateAddressCountry = (String) row["CorporateAddressCountry"];
        CountryNameLabel.Text = CorporateAddressCountry.Length <= 10 
                               ? CorporateAddressCountry
                               : CorporateAddressCountry.Substring(0, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes that his error is related to the string not being long enough. If his field is producing `DBNull` this will still throw exceptions.

Comment: I want to combine it with the concatenate with anotherfield country code   Eg: us-United states of Ame...

Comment: @JoelEtherton: Yes it does, but if it's not the case it provides also a way to debug the code to see the actual reason for the exception.

Comment: @ROBIN: If you want to combine it with another field, do it in the first place in the select, f.e. SQL-Server: `SELECT CountryCode + '-' + CorporateAddressCountry AS CountryInfo FROM TblCountry`. That's the most efficient and robust way and it allows also to sort by that field in the GridView. But you can also use my codebehind approach to combine these fields.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                Label countryNameLabel = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("CountryNameLabel");
                countryNameLabel.ToolTip = countryNameToolTip(countryNameLabel.Text);
                countryNameLabel.Text = countryNameDisplay(countryNameLabel.Text);
            }
        }

protected string countryNameDisplay(string key)
        {
            CustomerBusinessProvider business = new CustomerBusinessProvider();
            string country = business.CountryName(key);
            country = key + "-" + country;
            if (country.Length > 10)
            {
                country = country.Substring(0, 10) + "...";
            }
            return country;
        }
        protected string countryNameToolTip(string key)
        {
            CustomerBusinessProvider business = new CustomerBusinessProvider();
            return business.CountryName(key);
        }
```